# Number of combinations of a ternary sequence with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If you are given a ternary sequence (a sequence of numbers which only contain $0$, $1$, and $2$'s) which is composed of 15 numbers.  Let's say you must have $6$, $0's$, $5$, $1's$, and $4$, $2's$, then you can arrange this sequence in $\binom{15}{6}$ ways for the $0$'s, then we have $15-6=9$ places left to arrange the $1$'s.  So we can arrange the $1$'s in $\binom{9}{5}$ ways, and finally for the $2$'s we can arrange them in $\binom{4}{4}$ ways.  So in total we can have: $\binom{15}{6}\binom{9}{5}\binom{4}{4}$ ways of arranging this 15 ternary sequence.

However, what if we put a restriction on this sequence.  For example, the first $1$ must be preceded by a $0$ (ex: $2200100101011$).  Or the first $0$ precedes the first $1$ and the first $1$ precedes the first $2$ (ex: 000010201211212).  How would you go about counting the total number of ways now, with these type of restrictions?

Comment: This is too general...the method will depend on the nature of the restriction.  for the first, I'd remove one $0$ from the list, arrange the others, then insert that $0$ in front of the first $1$.  For the second, the pattern must be $0^a1X$ where $X$ has no such restrictions, and so on.

Comment: True, but for example for the first one, where you remove the 0 then place it back in.  When you put the 0 back into the equation, how would you go about counting the number of possible ways you can put that 0 back in front of the 1?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you wanted it to precede the first $1$ directly.  If all you want is that it appear somewhere before the the first $1$, then the pattern is $2^a0W$ where $W$ is a word without any such restriction.

Comment: To be clear, my point was not to focus on the particular solutions, but rather on the fact that each restriction requires special attention.  The method will strongly depend on the nature of the restriction...I strongly doubt that there is a single (useful) computational technique that works for all restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your initial thoughts on ternary arrangements, you have a multiset with three distinct elements and a number of repetitions - in your example, $\{(0,6),(1,5),(2,4)\}$ and the arrangements of the elements are simply the [trinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

$${15 \choose 6,5,4}=\frac{15!}{6!\,5!\,4!}$$

Then subsequent constraints can often be represented by breaking the possible strong into parts as [@lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) mentions. However the examples you describe I would attack in step-by-step insertion method using stars-and-bars assuming that the multiset specification remains the same.

Thus the first problem starts with $6$ zeroes and $6$ places to allocate the $1$s:

$$ 0\,\,\_\,\,0\,\,\_\,\,0\,\,\_\,\,0\,\,\_\,\,0\,\,\_\,\,0\,\,\_ $$

giving ${10 \choose 5}$ options, then ${15 \choose 4}$ further options to place the $2$s by a similar process (or by "masking" $0$s and $1$s together, same answer).

$$ {10 \choose 5}{15 \choose 4} = \frac{10!}{5!\,5!}\frac{15!}{11!\,4!} = \frac{15!}{11\cdot 5!\,5!\,4!}$$

Similarly the second problem restricts placement of the $2$s into the $1$s, then restricts placing the $1/2$ string into the $0$s.

$${8 \choose 4}{14 \choose 9}$$

Comment: wow, very nice to see how to count this in a different manner.  I ended up breaking it into cases and ended up with the exact same answer is all 3 cases.  I began by putting the 0 first then arranging the other 14 numbers, then 20 + 13 numbers, 220 + 12 numbers, 2220 + 11 numbers, and finally 22220 + 10 numbers and adding up all the cases.